# When ran the seven segment display flashes on the time in series instead of the intended output of counting down from 9 to the correct time

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

The desired output is to count down from 9999 to the correct time for example the time is 23:56 it should countdown from 9-2, 9-3, 9-5, 9-6 whilst displaying it on the display. When I ran this version of the code it did not run any of the functions or loops it just showed the time.

Here is the code:

```
#include "SevSeg.h"

// Create object
SevSeg sevseg;

// Number of digits in display
byte numDigits = 4;
// Display select pins
byte digitPins[] = {10, 11, 12, 13};
// Display segment pins A, B, C, D, E, F, G, DP
byte segmentPins[] = {9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4};
// Dropping resistors used
bool resistorsOnSegments = true;
// Display type
byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE;

int seconds = 50;
int minutes = 44;
int hours = 10;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const unsigned long interval = 1000; // interval of one second

// Digital pin to control Colleen's blinking (using A0)
const int colleenPin = A0;

// Flag to keep track of Colleen's state
bool colleenState = false;

unsigned long previousDigitMillis = 0;
const unsigned long digitInterval = 1000; // interval of one second for each digit

void setup() {
  // Start display object
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments);
  // Set brightness (optional)
  sevseg.setBrightness(90); // Adjust the brightness value as needed
  // Set the Colleen pin as an output pin for blinking
  pinMode(colleenPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // Toggle Colleen's state every second
    colleenState = !colleenState;
    digitalWrite(colleenPin, colleenState ? HIGH : LOW);

    seconds++;

    if (seconds >= 60) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;

      if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;

        if (hours >= 24) {
          hours = 0;
        }
      }

      int totalTime = hours * 100 + minutes;
      int amountsub = 9999 - totalTime;
      int starting_val = 9999;

      int digit1 = amountsub / 1000;   // Extract the thousands place digit
      int digit2 = (amountsub / 100) % 10;  // Extract the hundreds place digit
      int digit3 = (amountsub / 10) % 10;   // Extract the tens place digit
      int digit4 = amountsub % 10;          // Extract the ones place digit

      if (amountsub < 9000) {
        // Display the thousands digit
        if (currentMillis - previousDigitMillis >= digitInterval) {
          sevseg.setNumber(starting_val);
          previousDigitMillis = currentMillis;
          starting_val -= 1000; // Subtract 1000 from starting_val
        }

        // Display the hundreds digit
        if (currentMillis - previousDigitMillis >= digitInterval) {
          sevseg.setNumber(starting_val);
          previousDigitMillis = currentMillis;
          starting_val -= 100; // Subtract 100 from starting_val
        }

        // Display the tens digit
        if (currentMillis - previousDigitMillis >= digitInterval) {
          sevseg.setNumber(starting_val);
          previousDigitMillis = currentMillis;
          starting_val -= 10; // Subtract 10 from starting_val
        }

        // Display the ones digit
        if (currentMillis - previousDigitMillis >= digitInterval) {
          sevseg.setNumber(starting_val);
          previousDigitMillis = currentMillis;
          starting_val -= 1; // Subtract 1 from starting_val
        }
      }
    }

    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }

  // Set the number to display
  int time = hours * 100 + minutes;
  sevseg.setNumber(time);
  // Refresh the display
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
}
```

I tried getting help from chat gpt but I kept getting unintentional results.

Comment: At the end of loop you have code to set the current time on there.  It shouldn't be surprising then that this is what you see displayed.  After one second it will enter the big if timing if statement again and display something else for a few microseconds, but then at the end of loop you tell it to put the real time back up there.  Maybe that should be in an if statement and only happen once the countdown is done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is just visual effect you are after...right?

Not sure which option you are exactly looking for:

1. For each digit you want to count down from 9 to a pre-defined number and when that number is reached start counting down on the next digit?
2. simultaneously to count down on all digits till you reach the correct predefined number for that digit and stop whilst maybe some will keep counting down?

I may be completely wrong in understanding the question but here is example 1, it just outputs to the serial monitor:

```
#include "Arduino.h"


int target_time[] = {2,3,5,6}; //as in 23:56
int current_time[] = {10,9,9,9};
byte current_digit = 0; // the digit we are counting down from so that would be the first entry in the target_time array

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const unsigned long interval = 1000; // interval of one second



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  
  if (millis() - previousMillis >= interval) {

        if(current_digit < 4){
            if(current_time[current_digit] != target_time[current_digit]){
                current_time[current_digit]--;
            }else{
                current_digit++;
                current_time[current_digit]--;
               
            }
        }

        String time = String(current_time[0]) + String(current_time[1]) + ":" + String(current_time[2]) + "" + String(current_time[3]);

        Serial.println(time);
        
        previousMillis = millis();
  }
}
```

and here is example 2 (just the bits in the loop()

```
void loop() {
  
  if (millis() - previousMillis >= interval) {

        for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(current_time[i] != target_time[i]){
                current_time[i]--;
            
            }
        }

        String time = String(current_time[0]) + String(current_time[1]) + ":" + String(current_time[2]) + "" + String(current_time[3]);
        Serial.println(time);
        
        previousMillis = millis();
  }
}
```

Uh, sorry if this is a completely wrong answer